# When I type into excel sheet of One work book, it also getting typed into another open workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel

I was working on one excel sheet of workbook1, in between i opened another workbook i.e workbook2, after that whatever i am typing in workbook1 is also typed into workbook2 also. I have seen if we select multiplke worksheets in same workbook, then typing into one types in all. But here it is strange, it is happening between different workbooks. How can it be??

Comment: Are there any active formulas on the first sheet or is this newly created workbook from opening Excel and clicking new? Does the same happen if you type in to the second workbook? Does it replace back to workbook 1?

Comment: This is happening to workbook 2 where i have formulas and values entered earlier. I did not try vice versa. another problem i was facing is, i have one opened work book eg. workbook 1, then i opened another workbook which i downloaded from bank (monthly statement in excel format), then suddenly all values (where formula is present) in workbook 1 is converting into #VALUE error.